# Speeding up calculation of $\sum_{x\in S}\binom{n+x}{x}\mod 2$ for a given set $S$

Tags: combinatorics, modular-arithmetic, simulation

This is for some simulations I'm trying to run, and since there are slower parts in my simulation, I want to speed up the processing of the below problem (since it isn't the core part).

What I have is a list of distinct numbers (or set) $S$ consisting of numbers in the range $[0, \approx10^5)$. This list is constant for every single *run*. I'm given a list of numbers $N$ (elements in this can be big, and are random). For each $n \in N$, I'm trying to calculate $\sum_{x\in S}\binom{n+x}{x}\mod 2$.

Naively, for every $n$, I have to loop through $S$ and sum up $\binom{n+x}{x} \mod 2$ ($\log n$ complexity each) and then get the final answer by modding 2 again.

I'm hoping there's some faster way to calculate this for any list $N$, with a fixed set $S$ per run. Any suggestions or ideas would be great, thank you!

PS: Essentially I need to calculate $\binom{n+x_1}{x_1} + \binom{n+x_2}{x_2} + ... + \binom{n+x_m}{x_m} \mod 2$. Any $x_i, x_j$ are distinct.

Comment: This doesn't change anything about the size of the computation, but $\binom{n}{k}\bmod 2$ is $1$ iff for each bit in the binary expansion of $k$, that same bit is also set in the binary expansion of $n$. Meaning you can just check `(n+x)&x == x` in code.

Comment: @orlp So essentially I could find the number of elements in $S$ whose set bits are a subset of $n$'s set bits?

Comment: No, because you have $n+x$ in the top part of the binomial, not $n$. Otherwise the answer would've been yes.

Comment: @orlp oh yes my bad

Comment: Note that @orlp's expression can be simplified to `(n & x) == 0` [parentheses necessary in C]. If $N$ can have many elements, it may be faster to build a lookup structure than to iterate over $S$ for each $n\in N$.

Comment: @DanielFischer What sort of a lookup data structure do you imply?

Answer (score 0):

This may be helpful:

Since $\dbinom{n+x}{x}= \dfrac{(n+x)!}{n!\,x!}$, to find out the parity of this you can check whether there are the same or more powers of $2$ in $(n+x)!$ than there are in $n!\,x!$.

You can count powers of $2$ in $m!$ by repeatedly halving $m$ and discarding any fractional part. So for example for $53!$, set $a_0=53$ and $a_{i+1} = \lfloor a_i/2\rfloor$ and sum from $a_1$ onwards:
$$v_2(53!) =   26+13+6+3+1 = 49$$

(meaning $53! /2^{49}$ is an odd integer).

You can precalculate these multiplicities once for the factorials of each $x_i\in S$ and $n_j\in N$, and of course $v_2(x_i!\,n_j!) = v_2(x_i!) + v_2(n_j!)$. However I don't immediately see a way around calculating individual multiplicities for the factorial of each sum $n_j{+}x_i$ - although this is just a matter of undertaking the above calculation in each case.